# Importing jsPDF causing optimization bailout warning in angular

Tags: angular, jspdf

I am quite new to Angular build and I am developing a feature where in I want to download/print the reports in PDF format. I installed the packages *jsPDF* and *jsPDF-autotable* using npm to convert the json data to pdf, but while serving the angular project with import in the component

```
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';
import autoTable from 'jspdf-autotable';
```

It gives following warnings:

```
Warning: \node_modules\canvg\lib\index.es.js depends on 'raf'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: \node_modules\canvg\lib\index.es.js depends on 'core-js/modules/es.string.match.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: \node_modules\canvg\lib\index.es.js depends on 'core-js/modules/es.string.replace.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: \node_modules\canvg\lib\index.es.js depends on 'core-js/modules/es.promise.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.    
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: \node_modules\canvg\lib\index.es.js depends on 'core-js/modules/es.string.starts-with.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

Warning: \node_modules\canvg\lib\index.es.js depends on 'core-js/modules/es.array.iterator.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

Warning: \node_modules\canvg\lib\index.es.js depends on 'core-js/modules/es.array.reduce.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

Warning: \node_modules\canvg\lib\index.es.js depends on 'core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.iterator.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

Warning: \node_modules\canvg\lib\index.es.js depends on 'core-js/modules/es.string.ends-with.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

Warning: \node_modules\canvg\lib\index.es.js depends on 'core-js/modules/es.string.split.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

Warning: \node_modules\canvg\lib\index.es.js depends on 'core-js/modules/es.string.trim.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

Warning: \node_modules\canvg\lib\index.es.js depends on 'core-js/modules/es.array.index-of.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

Warning: \node_modules\canvg\lib\index.es.js depends on 'core-js/modules/es.string.includes.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

Warning: \node_modules\canvg\lib\index.es.js depends on 'core-js/modules/es.array.reverse.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

Warning: \node_modules\canvg\lib\index.es.js depends on 'core-js/modules/es.regexp.to-string.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: \node_modules\canvg\lib\index.es.js depends on 'raf'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

I went through many pages on web, but did not get the proper solution.
Do not want to add the libraries in *allowedCommonJsDependencies* options in *angular.json* as it just suppresses the warning.

I am using angular build:

```
"@angular/cli": "^11.2.14",
"jspdf": "^2.5.1",
"jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.28"
```

How should I solve this issue?

- Should I proceed with this warning and push the code to production? OR
- As I am not using `addSvgAsImage` function, I should move to custom-webpack build and move the libraries like *canvg*, *raf* to *externals*? OR
- Should I try using other library like *pdfmake*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also facing the same problem, I fixed it by doing

```
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
          "jspdf-autotable",
          "raf",
          "core-js"
        ]
```

Update you angular.json with the following and you wont get those warnings, read more on [Optimization bailouts official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies)

Comment: This just suppresses the error or warnings, but does not work as the permanent solution @jibin-philipose

Comment: You're correct, It only suppresses those warnings because libraries like jspdf still depend on the commonJS to generate the bundles, there is no other option than to wait for the author to update the library with ESModules for jspdf or you can look for alternatives but If you've got a strong requirement for this particular feature then just suppress the warning and use it in prod as many are doing.

Comment: This cleared my doubt, thank you so much for the explanation.